# Omitir resultado entre dos tablas con Entity Eramework

Tags: entity-framework, join

He intentado hacer un join en **Entity Framework** (EF) pero no he podido, la consulta en SQL Server es asi mas o menos

```
select c.*
from Contratos c
   right Join ContratosOrdenInicio coi
   on c.Codigo <>  coi.CodContrato
```

**Ocupo los contratos que no tengan ContratosOrdenInicio**

El problema de hacer esta consulta es que en el EF no encuento un equivalente al **distinto (<>)**

Lo que tengo en EF es el siguiente codigo.

```
public async  Task<List<ContratoDTO>> GetContratosPorLicitacion(string licitacion)
    {
        return await
            (from c in _context.Contratos
             join co in _context.ContratosOrdenesCompra//ContratosOrdenInicio
             on c.Codigo equals co.CodContrato
             where c.Licitacion.Contains(licitacion)
             select new ContratoDTO()
             {
                 Codigo = c.Codigo,
                 Licitacion = c.Licitacion,
                 NumeroContrato = c.NumeroContrato,
                 Proveedor = c.Proveedor
             }).ToListAsync();
    }
```

y donde esta el **equals** debo poner el equivalente a **distinto** <>
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Distinto es ! =

Comment: Hice un cambio a la consulta, talvez no me habia explicado bien

Comment: La consulta que tienes en SQL no devuelve lo que explicas que quieres obtener (suponiendo que usas el verbo _ocupar_ en lugar de _querer_ o _necesitar_, cosa muy extraña). Sugiero que comiences por asegurarte de tener la consulta correcta en SQL.

Comment: pon la consulta completa que tienes en sql

Comment: La consulta que esta ahi es la consulta completa, es pequeña, pero no se como hacer el equivalente de  <> en EF

Comment: Como te comentan el distinto en C# es !=. Pero lo que dices no tiene la misma logica con tu query ni con tu consulta linQ. Lo que estoy entendiendo es  que ¿quieres los Contratos que no tienen ContratosOrdenInicio?

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta tu comentario en negritas. Es más sencillo si los separas.
Donde primero  tomas los contratos de inicio.

```
var ContratosOrdenInicio = from co in _context.ContratosOrdenesCompra
                           select co.CodContrato;
```

Y en el where de contratos verificas cuales de ellos no existen con Contains falso.

```
var Contratos = from c in _context.Contratos
                where !ContratosOrdenInicio.Contains(c.Codigo) && c.Licitacion.Contains(licitacion)
                select c new ContratoDTO()
         {
             Codigo = c.Codigo,
             Licitacion = c.Licitacion,
             NumeroContrato = c.NumeroContrato,
             Proveedor = c.Proveedor
         };
```

> Contains funciona como la sentencia IN de SQL; Y si le antepones el signo ! el
> resultado se revierte.

Comment: me funciono correctamente, gracias